# How to resolve string indices must be integers in data analysis?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have downloaded some data, so I wanted to change some values into boolean type:

```py
for dataset in loan_df:
    dataset['Gender'] = dataset['Gender'].replace({'male' : 1 , 'female' : 0} , inplace = True)
```

but it is giving me this error :

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I also tried this code :

```py
for dataset in loan_df:
    dataset['Gender'] = dataset['Gender'].map({'male' : 1 , 'female' : 0}).astype(int)
```

But it is still giving the same error. Do you know how to resolve this error?

Comment: Is loan_df a list of dataframes or just a single dataframe?

Comment: loan_df  = pd.read_csv('example'.csv)

Comment: kindly share a sample dataset, with expected output

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `loan_df` is a pandas DataFrame, therefore when you are iterating trough it with the `for` loop, the iterator is a `Series`. That is why, when you try `['Gender']` you are actually indexing it and an integer is expected.

The solution would be to remove the loop:

```
loan_df['Gender'] = loan_df['Gender'].replace({'male' : 1 , 'female' : 0})
```

Comment: by using this method, all the data under gender is replaced with None

Comment: @chogomogo fixed. Next time it will be much easier if you can provide a small snapshot of your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming loan_df is a singular DataFrame, I create an emulated DataFrame like so:

```
loan_df = pd.DataFrame({"Gender":["male","female"]})
```

I reproduced the error with the following code, but I also included print statements:

```
for dataset in loan_df:
    print(dataset)
    print(type(dataset))
    dataset['Gender'] = dataset['Gender'].replace({'male' : 1 , 'female' : 0} , inplace = True)
```

Output:

```
Gender
<class 'str'>
...

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

When you iterate through the DataFrame, `dataset` will be the column names.

Try using the below command:

```
loan_df['Gender'].replace({'male' : 1 , 'female' : 0} , inplace = True)
```

By indicating the inplace parameter, you do not have to reassign it back to `loan_df`.

Comment: this is providing none type even if i apply this method on other columns of dataframe

Comment: @chogo-mogo Could you tell me the new line of code you are attempting. I believe you are attempting `loan_df['Gender'] = loan_df['Gender'].replace({'male' : 1 , 'female' : 0} , inplace = True)` which does result in none types, but if you do `loan_df['Gender'].replace({'male' : 1 , 'female' : 0} , inplace = True)` by itself or `loan_df['Gender'] = loan_df['Gender'].replace({'male' : 1 , 'female' : 0} )`, it should work.

Comment: thanks for help,ya after using the loan_df['Gender'].replace({'male' : 1 , 'female' : 0} , inplace = True) it was working

Comment: @chogomogo awesome! If you don't mind, please select my answer as the best answer (if you think so).